# Angular structural directive duplicate components

Tags: angular

I my angular application I have a structural directive to show/hide components based on user role.
In some cases (login) all the components with the directive are duplicated until  page refresh. So I tried to clear the viewContainer before to create it and now the problems seems solved.
But is it the right way? and why

This is the directive in the html.

```
<button *securityUtils="loggedUserService.roles" 
  mat-icon-button routerLink="/subscription">
```

And this is the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[securityUtils]"
})
export class SecurityUtils implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  private _securityUtils: Subscription;
  @Input()
  set securityUtils(value: Observable<string[]>) {
    this._securityUtils = value.subscribe(roles => this.isAuthorized(roles));
  }

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private security: SecurityService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._securityUtils.unsubscribe();
  }

  isAuthorized(roles: string[]) {
    if (roles != null) {
      if (this.security.isAuthorized(roles)) {
        this.viewContainer.clear();   ******<-- clear before create***
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not just *ngIf?

Comment: I need to use my directive...

Comment: But why? You're just doing the same thing.

Comment: I have to add some input and more complexity so the question is how to solve this with custom directive...

Comment: Same is happening with me! (1) Were you able to find reason behind this? (2)  How did you fix that issue?

Comment: Hi, it's not an issue, every time you have to show/hide something with a structural directive you need to assume that is already in "show" mode so if you do createEmbeddedView you are replicating the template